# MongoDB: How to merge two collections/databases together into one?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I have two databases named: `DB_A` and `DB_B`.

Each database has one collection with same name called `store`.

Both collections have lots lots of documents that have exactly the same structure `{ key:" key1", value: "value1" }`, etc.

Actually, I was supposed to only create `DB_A` and insert all documents into `DB_A`. But later when I did my second round of inserting, I made a mistake by typing the wrong name as the database name.

So now, each database has a size of 32GB, I wish to merge two databases.

One problem/constraint is that the free space available now is only 15GB, so I can't just `copy` all things from `DB_B` to `DB_A`.

I am wondering if I can perform some kind of "move" to merge the two databases? I prefer the most efficient way as simply reinserting 32GB into `DB_A` will take quite a time.

Comment: Take first document from DB_B. Insert it into DB_A if not already there. Delete it from DB_B. Repeat until done.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev If I just delete DB_B and reinsert everything (of DB_B) freshly into DB_A using my code, will this way be slower than the one you suggested?

Comment: If all your data is in DB_B, then you can drop DB_A and just rename DB_B.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev no, half is in DB_A and half is in DB_B

Comment: @SergioTulentsev could you please tell me how to drop a database (not a collection) in mongodb? also via mongodb command line, how to achieve your way?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev how to take one doc from DB_B and then insert it into DB_A, via commands?

Comment: As Sergio has said, this can unfortunately only be done manually and through a script (whatever is your preferred language).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev could you please write your comment as answer? I will mark it. Thanks

Comment: @SergioTulentsev by the way, the drop database action is db.dropDatabase()

Comment: Yes, you're right. Forgot about that :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the easiest (and maybe the only) way is to write a script that merges the two databases document after document.

1. Get first document from DB_B.
2. Insert it into DB_A if needed.
3. Delete it from DB_B.
4. Repeat until done.

Instead of deleting documents from source db (DB_B), you may want to just read documents in batches. This should be more performant, but slightly more difficult to code (especially if you never done such a thing).

Comment: how to switch between different databases db_a and db_b? I am trying to write a script in python. Need some guidance.

Comment: @rkatkam: just create two separate connections.

Comment: Ok. One more qtn, what if I have two separate databases with same name. How should I proceed? Currently I am having them on different machines. I want to merge them. Any idea?

Comment: @rkatkam: so, what's the problem there?

Comment: I am having 2 separate mongodb instances. If I try to use one, the other will be overridden. And how is it possible to keep both of them in same machine?

Comment: @rkatkam: I have no idea what you're talking about, but you can run them on different machines. Or on the same machine, but on different ports. Or you could rename one of the databases and run both of them in the same mongodb instance.

Comment: I am also thinking to copydatabase. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Starting `Mongo 4.2`, the new aggregation stage [`$merge`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html) can be used to merge the content of a collection in another collection in another database:

```
// > use db1
// > db.collection.find()
//   { "_id" : 1, "key" : "a", "value" : "b" }
//   { "_id" : 2, "key" : "c", "value" : "d" }
//   { "_id" : 3, "key" : "a", "value" : "b" }
// > use db2
// > db.collection.find()
//   { "_id" : 1, "key" : "e", "value" : "f" }
//   { "_id" : 4, "key" : "a", "value" : "b" }
// > use db1
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $merge: { into: { db: "db2", coll: "coll" } } }
])
// > use db2
// > db.collection.find()
//   { "_id" : 1, "key" : "a", "value" : "b" }
//   { "_id" : 2, "key" : "c", "value" : "d" }
//   { "_id" : 3, "key" : "a", "value" : "b" }
//   { "_id" : 4, "key" : "a", "value" : "b" }
```

By default, when the target and the source collections contain a document with the same `_id`, `$merge` will replace the document from the target collection with the document from the source collection. In order to customise this behaviour, check `$merge`'s `whenMatched` parameter.